# How change the "loadOnDemandItemTemplate" from RadListView in NativeScript-Vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I read the documentation about Radlistview at [RadListView Load on Demand](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/load-on-demand) but I don't know how to do change the template for "loadOnDemandItemTemplate" in NativeScript-Vue.

The default template contains: "Load More" and "Loading" labels.

```
<RadListView for="item in articles"
        layout="linear" 
        loadOnDemandMode="Manual" 
        @loadMoreDataRequested="onLoadMoreItemsRequested"
        @itemTap="onItemTap" >
    <v-template>
        <GridLayout>...</GridLayout>
    </v-template>

</RadListView>
```

I want to change the default template for loadOnDemand.

Thx

Comment: I don't think that is supported in Vue yet, so you might have to do it with core JavaScript, listen to the loaded event and set `loadOnDemandItemTemplate` on `nativeView`.

Comment: Can you explain me how to achieve this? I tried to change the property but nothing

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=vMv0dK) how you could do this with Vue.

```
       onLoaded: function(args) {
            var listView = args.object;
            listView.loadOnDemandMode = "Manual";
            listView.loadOnDemandItemTemplate = `<GridLayout height="100" backgroundColor="red"></GridLayout>`;
        }
```

But it works only with iOS, with Android it's a [known issue](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/700).

Comment: Thanks, I resolved partially on Android, change the String value used by the Java class LoadOnDemand

Comment: Where to find this value?